# Magetno 2: Theme Configuration Goes To 404 After Save

Tags: magento2, php, admin, configuration, backend

I'm using `Magento 2.3.5`, I'm scratching my head for a couple of days, the issue is when I go to `Theme Configuration`, do any changes and hit `Save Configuration`, the page goes to `404 error: Page not found.`. Like This:

[image]

`**Please help me out with this one.**`

Answer (score 1):

I had this issues few months back and after searching on google I found:
[Design Configuration Not Saving showing 404 page on sub-directory](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/229553/design-configuration-not-saving-showing-404-page-on-sub-directory)

And it works fine for me. Hope this helps!